# HTML Page Navigation for index page

Tags: html

I have a simple website that I paid someone to set up for me to post articles on - the entries are all done on the index.html page. I have about 12 entries now and I would like to set up page navigation... I'd like to display about 6-8 articles on the first page, and then have a bar on the bottom with either "next" or "page 2, page 3, page 4" etc, (or both), for users to click through to the next 5 articles, while keeping them all in chronological order and the rest of the site static. The site was set up by someone I hired on Craigslist, and I have a basic knowledge of HTML that is sufficient to update the index page and create new pages. There is a navigational element to the template already coded into the index page, but it has been commented out. I'm not sure how to use this specific format to create multiple pages with older articles on it.

```
                <!--- <div class="page-navi">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> ---!>
            <!-- End Page Navi -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is completely static and composed entirely of `html` files, your only option is to split your `index.html` into several files and insert navigation code manually. This is tedious and error prone if for example, you wanted to have five articles per page and wanted newest first, you will need to shift the oldest article in each file into another file whenever you added a new article. This can be really bad if you have 100 articles over 20 different files.

Alternatively, you can do some back-end development to do this for you with `PHP`, `javascipt`, `python`, `clojure`, `your programming language of choice`. If you are willing to use something entirely different, `wordpress` and other blogging platforms are worth considering.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer - it is very helpful to know the limitations of the HTML files I am using, and it is extremely helpful to know that I'd have to learn a programming language to achieve my idea result. saves me lots of time searching for a solution. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the whole website by using multiple `.html` files, then you would need to duplicate this piece of code to all of the files:

```
<div class="page-navi">
     <ul>
           <li><a href=".../page1.html" class="current">1</a></li>
           <li><a href=".../page2.html">2</a></li>
           <li><a href=".../page3.html">3</a></li>
           <li><a href=".../page2.html">Next</a></li>
           <li><a href=".../page5.html">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You should change `...` with your actual url and change page numbers according to the requirements of each separate page.

Comment: my articles exist all on separate .html files that are linked to from the .index page, but none of the articles are long enough to warranty pagination, nor do I want to do that. I just want to limit the front page of my website to the most recent articles, and then there are also thumbnail links to more on the right hand side of the page (www.kristinleeb.com). that being said, and I'm sorry if this is an amateur question, how do the edits you provided know where each page would start/stop? going to try it out now. thank you!

Comment: This snippet of code won't work by itself. It assumes you have a back-end that knows what to do with the page numbers or an `.htaccess` file or similar. If you're splitting your `html` files up into clusters of articles, you'd link to the `html` file instead of `?page=`.

Comment: My fault. Totally forgot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your site is plain html, then you can split articles accross pages e.g. pge1.html, page2.html etc. And then.create links such as

Comment: yeah, that's pretty much the only option I have if I can't figure anything else out. The only reason I don't want to do this is because then I will have to change the page numbers every time I add a new page in order to keep things chronological. I already manually update my index page and my RSS feed when I add a new article so your suggestion is feasible, just tedious. thank you!